# Colocar icono en un SelectMenu de Jquery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quisiera colocar un icono en el item seleccionado de un SelectMenu item.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Asi de esta manera.
He conseguido añadir los iconos en el desplegable, pero no consigo ponerlo ahi.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El codigo que he usado es este:

```
<div class="select-lang">
        <?
            $check = $sql->query("SELECT * FROM `".PREFIX."langs` WHERE `active` = '1' ORDER BY `int_name` ASC");
            echo "<select class='languages'>";
            while($show = $check->fetch_object()){
                echo "<option value='".$show->lang."' data-class='".$show->lang."' data-title='".$show->int_name."'>".$show->name."</option>";
            }
            echo "</select>";
        ?>
    </div>
```

en un principio genero toda la estructura con lo que tengo almacenado en la base de datos.
Ahora con Jquery UI los siguiente:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.widget( "custom.iconselectmenu", $.ui.selectmenu, {
                _renderItem: function( ul, item ) {
                var li = $( "<li>", { text: item.label, "title": item.element.attr( "data-title" ) } );

                if ( item.disabled ) {
                    li.addClass( "ui-state-disabled" );
                }

                $( "<span>", {
                    style: item.element.attr( "data-style" ),
                    "class": "ui-icon " + item.element.attr( "data-class" )
                })
                .appendTo( li );

                    return li.appendTo( ul );
                }
            });
            $('.languages')
            .iconselectmenu()
            .iconselectmenu('menuWidget')
            .addClass('ui-menu-icons customicons');
        });
    </script>
```

Pues esta es la duda.
Saludos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si miras el código HTML generado, puedes ver que el icono viene definido por la imagen de fondo del `span` especificada en esta parte de tu código JS:

```
$( "<span>", {
    style: item.element.attr( "data-style" ),
    "class": "ui-icon " + item.element.attr( "data-class" )
})
```

Ese `span` tendrá la clase "ui-icon" y también la clase especificada en el `data-class` del `option` en el menú de selección. Por lo que, para cambiar el icono, sólo tendrías que especificar un nuevo icono en CSS. En tu caso, suponiendo que `$show->lang` es "es", sería algo como esto:

```
span.ui-icon.es { 
    background-image: url(http://enlace.a.bandera.de/españa.jpg);
}
```

Luego para el caso de la opción seleccionada, puedes seguir un método similar pero para la clase "ui-selectmenu-text". Así sólo faltaría añadir un poco de JavaScript para actualizar la clase de "ui-selectmenu-text" cuando se pulse en una opción y cuando se cargue la página (para que la opción por defecto también tenga icono sin necesidad de pulsar nada).

---

Aquí dejo un ejemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.widget( "custom.iconselectmenu", $.ui.selectmenu, {
    _renderItem: function( ul, item ) {
      var li = $( "<li>", { text: item.label, "title": item.element.attr( "data-title" ) } );

      if ( item.disabled ) {
        li.addClass( "ui-state-disabled" );
      }

      $( "<span>", {
        style: item.element.attr( "data-style" ),
        "class": "ui-icon " + item.element.attr( "data-class" )
      })
      .appendTo( li );

      return li.appendTo( ul );
    }
  });
  $('.languages')
  .iconselectmenu()
  .iconselectmenu('menuWidget')
  .addClass('ui-menu-icons customicons');
  
  // cambiar la clase de la opción seleccionada cuando se pulsa en una de las opciones en la lista
  $("body").on("click",".ui-menu li.ui-menu-item", function() {
      var target = $(this).closest(".ui-menu").attr("aria-labelledby");
      var tclass = $(this).find("span").attr("class").replace("ui-icon ", "");
      $("#" + target).find(".ui-selectmenu-text").attr("class", "ui-selectmenu-text " + tclass);
  });
  
  // activar la bandera al principio
  $(".ui-selectmenu-button").each(function() {
      var tclass = $("#" + $(this).attr("id").replace("-button", "") + " option").first().attr("data-class");
      $(this).find(".ui-selectmenu-text").addClass(tclass);
  });
 
  
});
```

```css
.ui-selectmenu-button {
  width:200px !important;
}

.ui-selectmenu-text { 
  padding-left:40px !important;
  background-position: 13px center;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}


span.ui-icon.en,
.ui-selectmenu-text.en { 
  background-image: url( http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fatcow/farm-fresh/16/flag-england-icon.png) !important;
}

span.ui-icon.es,
.ui-selectmenu-text.es { 
  background-image: url( http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fatcow/farm-fresh/16/flag-spain-icon.png);
}

span.ui-icon.fr,
.ui-selectmenu-text.fr { 
  background-image: url( http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fatcow/farm-fresh/16/flag-france-icon.png);
}

span.ui-icon.de,
.ui-selectmenu-text.de { 
  background-image: url( http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fatcow/farm-fresh/16/flag-germany-icon.png);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css">

<select class="languages">
  <option value="de" data-class="de" data-title="Alemán">Alemán</option>
  <option value="es" data-class="es" data-title="Español">Español</option>
  <option value="fr" data-class="fr" data-title="Francés">Francés</option>
  <option value="en" data-class="en" data-title="Inglés">Inglés</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Gracias @Alvaro Montoro, lo de aplicar la hoja de estilos lo tengo hecho, pero mi intencion es que el icono se quede en el item seleccionado.

Comment: @ElTitoBarte para el item seleccionado, tendrías que aplicar un método similar pero para la clase `.ui-selectmenu-text`. He modificado el ejemplo para que cada vez que se pulse en una opción se actualice la clase del seleccionado y se muestre la bandera (quizás no de la mejor manera, pero funciona). Faltaría poner la bandera cuando la página se cargue y se cree el dropdown

Comment: perfecto!! esto ultimo si me ha funcionado. Gracias.